# How to pass multiple variables in a foreach loop in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am sure there is an easy way to do it and even if for loop should be used please let me know how to do it. I am new to laravel. I have an array like this in my PagesController:

```
public function faq()
    {
        $faqs=array(
            'questions'=>[
                'question1',
                'question2',
                'question3'
                ]
        );

        return view('frontend.pages.faq')->with($faqs);
}
```

and my faq page has the following code:

```
 @if (count($questions)>0)
    @foreach($questions as $question)
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card card--faq mb-2">
            <div class="bdv-btn card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="btn btn-link w-100" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>
                        {{$question}}
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            @endforeach()
            @endif
```

Since it's an accordion, id for each question and answer is unique. And I would like to create something like heading{{$headingCount}} and collapse{{"$collapseCount}}

Some previous posts suggested using for loop would be a better approach but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$key => $value` in `foreach()` like follows:

```
@foreach($questions as $key => $question)
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card card--faq mb-2">
            <div class="bdv-btn card-header" id="heading{{$key}}">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="btn btn-link w-100" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{$key}}" aria-controls="collapse{{$key}}">
                        <span class="fa fa-question-circle"></span>
                        {{$question}}
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and it would help me in some cases but here I need it to say forexample headingOne and collapseOne etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function faq()
{
     $questions = [ 'question1', 'question2', 'question3'];

    return view('frontend.pages.faq')->with('questions',$questions);
```

}

Comment: This would give me list of questions again which I can already get. What I wish to do is pass in multiple variables so for example each question as a unique id.

Comment: Ok to access the unique I'd of each of the question foreach($questions as $key => $question){ } hence $key will hold the unique I'd for each of the question

Comment: Yes but as mentioned in the question, I need the ids to say One, Two Three and not 1, 2,3